# Create a feature module in angular - 6

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a feature module that will handle my "font awesome" icon imports and import it to the app module but it giving me this error when i try to add an icon

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'.
```

App module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';   
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';   
import { IconsModule } from './icons.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [         
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    IconsModule
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Icons feature module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import  { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faArrowAltRight } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'; 

library.add(faArrowAltRight);

    @NgModule({
      imports: [CommonModule, FontAwesomeModule],
      declarations: [

      ],
      providers: [],
      exports: []
    })

    export class IconsModule {}
```

Comment: did you buy pro-version of font-awesome?

Comment: @Chellappan Yes. It worked fine before i split it from the app module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export modules that you need to use in you app or other module, below is sample

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FontAwesomeModule],
  declarations: [

  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [FontAwesomeModule]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it. I added this :

```
import  { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome'
```

To the app module imports.